# Qual a palavra para "mudança temporária"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário

Existe uma palavra que é um sinônimo de "*mudança*", "*alteração*", "*modificação*", mas que deixe claro que é por um período passageiro? Pra ser usada quando sabemos que o que foi mudado vai, posteriormente, voltar a ser o que era antes.

Se possível, que fique claro que **não é** uma mudança "*transitória*": que começa em "A", muda temporariamente pra "B" e depois termina em "C". Mas sim uma mudança que volta pra "A" depois de passar temporariamente por "B".

Comment: Eu diria que transitório é genérico, no sentido de que é possível se ter "C"="A". Por exemplo, uma hipertensão que se manifesta apenas durante a gestação (ou seja, se volta ao estado anterior, normal, após o parto) pode [ser chamada](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0066-782X2009001300017) de "hipertensão transitória" e, similarmente, há também a [osteoporose transitória](http://www.scielo.mec.pt/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1646-58302017000100008).

Comment: Justamente, eu queria um termo que, ao contrário de "transitório", desse uma noção de não transitório. Além disso, "transitório" é um adjetivo.

Comment: Sim, sei que é adjetivo, meu comentário foi só sobre tua observação sobre "transitório", não uma sugestão de palavra. Nesse sentido, que diferença você vê entre "transitório" e "passageiro" nesse caso? Porque você pede na pergunta que implique ser "passageiro", só que este é sinônimo de "transitório".

Comment: Quanto à palavra procurada, não encontro uma sugestão muito boa no momento. Talvez algumas possibilidades, dependendo do contexto, poderiam ser "oscilação" ou "flutuação" (como numa descrição de preços ou temperaturas, que mudam, mas se espera que voltem a uma linha base), ou até "fase", "estágio", "período".

Comment: Algo como provisório? momentâneo? temporâneo?

Comment: @stafusa "oscilção" e "flutuação" são uma excelente aproximação! Mas dão uma ideia de continuidade ou fluidez entre os estados A e B. Eu busco uma mudança sem intermédios... vou tentar melhora a pergunta.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, algo como "mudança provisória", "mudança momentânea" ou "mudança temporânea". Um substantivo sinônimo de mudança e que também capture o significado desses adjetivos que você citou.